# Как получить список из файла с помощью JSON

Tags: python, синтаксис

Не получается получить обратно список в Python переменную.

```
# запись списка res в файл
f = open('list_new.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
#f.writelines(res) 
json.dump(res, f)
f.close()

# чтение списка из  файла
res_nw = [] # новый список
f = open('list_new.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для чтения
#f.writelines(res) 
json.load(res_nw, f)
print ('Список получен из файла:')
print(str(res_nw)) # печать нового списка
f.close()
```

Выдает ошибку :

> typeerror load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1):

Функция json.load в качестве аргумента принимает объект файла, а не результирующую переменную, поэтому фрагмент чтения файла в вашем коде должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
f = open('list_new.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для чтения
res_nw = json.load(f)
print ('Список получен из файла:')
print(str(res_nw)) # печать нового списка
f.close()
```